# Twitter update using Python throwing an error

Tags: python, twitter

I wrote the following piece of code for updating my Twitter status using Python.

```
import tweepy

tweet=raw_input("Enter the status that you want to update to Twitter: ")

def get_api(cfg):
  auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(cfg['consumer_key'], cfg['consumer_secret'])
  auth.set_access_token(cfg['access_token'], cfg['access_token_secret'])
  return tweepy.API(auth)

def main():
  # Fill in the values noted in previous step here
  cfg = { 
    "consumer_key"        : "VALUE",
    "consumer_secret"     : "VALUE",
    "access_token"        : "VALUE",
    "access_token_secret" : "VALUE" 
    }

  api = get_api(cfg)
  status = api.update_status(status=tweet) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

The code works most of the times on different machines. However, there was a problem which I have described below.

```
>>status = api.update_status(status=tweet)
raise TweepError('Failed to send request: %s' % e)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.
```

I have created a virtual environment for my twitter application within which I have installed `tweepy` using `pip install` on Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you working behind any sock/proxy?

Comment: Yes, I was working on an institute's proxy. But it was working for some and not working for the rest!

Comment: Can you post your `pip freeze`?

Comment: gotta go so I leave some info here and hope this helps. After reading source code of `tweepy`, I can see [it uses `requests` lib](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/binder.py#L181-L189) so your exception [comes from `requests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/5259b374512ec4e47785f5004ec6ad30dafe906f/requests/adapters.py#L39-L43). I think you missed some dependencies (`PySocks` or `requests[socks]`) as [stated in source code](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/socks.py)

Comment: So how do we resolve those dependencies. Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: Actually I was teaching this to someone and they had this error on their machine. Hence I am unable to reproduce this error on my machine. Thanks for asking.